# Theories with Skolem function

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, computability

We say an $\mathcal{L}$-theory $T$ has built in Skolem functions if for all $\mathcal{L}$-formula $\phi(x,\bar{y})$ there is a function symbol $f$ such that $T\models \forall\bar{y}(\exists x\phi(x,\bar{y} )\rightarrow \phi(f(\bar{y}),\bar{y}))$.

$ \textbf{Question}.$ Let a theory $T$ have built in Skolem functions. How can we prove that $T$ has $\forall$-axiomatization?

Comment: I think you are referring to the idea of "Skolemization" to rid the axioms of existential quantifiers.  See for example [Skolem normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form).  The details of your "built in Skolem functions" are needed if you intend to "prove" $T$ has universally quantified axioms only, but the idea presented in broad terms is clear enough for most purposes.

Comment: @hardmath The OP is referring to the model theoretic notion of definable Skolem functions, see here: http://modeltheory.wikia.com/wiki/Skolem_functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to combine two facts to prove this:

1. If a theory $T$ has built-in (also called definable) Skolem functions, then every substructure of a model of $T$ is an elementary substructure.
2. A theory $T$ has a universal axiomatization if and only if it's class of models is closed under substructure.